# Need help creating a power series for with specific condtions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I needed to give an example of a power series that satisfies the following conditions: interval of convergence is [$e$,$\pi$)
I came up with this series: $$\sum_{n}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{\pi-e}\right)^n\left(x-\frac{1}{2}(e+\pi)\right)^n$$
However I'm pretty sure my series does not converge at $e$, i.e. my interval of convergence is ($e$,$\pi$) not [$e$,$\pi$)  . Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you tried to take the geometric series $p(x)=\sum_n x^n$ and shift/scale it so the interval of convergence matches up.  This won't work, unfortunately, because the interval of convergence of $p(x)$ is $(-1,1)$, and the sum does not converge on the boundary.  You'll need to start with a power series that converges on a half-open interval.  The easiest example is:

$$
h(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}
$$

This series converges absolutely when $\vert x\vert<1$, *and* converges for $x=-1$, but fails to converge for $x=1$.  In other words, its interval of convergence is $[-1,1)$.  Now you can apply the appropriate scaling/shift to move this interval to $[e,\pi)$.  Enjoy!